# Typescript narrow down types in existing classes

Tags: typescript

I'm currently using an existing package that has a type `MyType` defined

```
export type MyType<T = unknown> = (params: {[k: string]: any}) => T;
```

This type is implemented in the constructor of a class.

```
export class MyClass<T = unknown> {
  constructor(
    id: string,
    value: T | MyType<T>,
    options?: any,
  );
}
```

What I would like to do is to create a class extending the `MyClass` class with more specific values for the `params` parameter in the `MyType` type:

```
type MyNewType = {
  param1: number;
  param2: number;
}
const myVar = new MyClass('exampleId', async (params: MyNewType) => { 
  return params.param1 * params.param2 
}
```

However, typescript (correctly) complains that the types are not compatible, since `MyNewType` has REQUIRED keys, while the `{[k: string]: any}` type doesn't have any required keys. I could solve the error by simply using `Partial<MyNewType>` instead of `MyNewType`, but then I have to do all sorts of type-checking inside the function itself. Changing the definitions of `MyType` and `MyClass` are also not possible.

My question is: How can I use (or extend) `MyClass` so that I can give more specific types to the `params` parameter and I don't have to do extra type checking inside my function.

Comment: Maybe Pick and Omit are what you are looking for? This way you can remove specific properties from a type or select only the ones you need instead of making everything a partial property.

Comment: This wouldn't work right, since the original type includes an empty set, and `MyNewType` would never contain an empty set. So by picking and omitting from `{[k: string]: any}` I can't really get to `MyNewType` right? But maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make params a generic too:

```js
export type MyType<T = unknown, Params extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> = (params: Params) => T;

type MyNewType = {
  param1: number;
  param2: number;
}

export class MyClass<T = unknown> {
  constructor(
    id: string,
    value: T | MyType<T, MyNewType>,
    options?: any,
  ) { };
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the definitions of MyType and MyClass are also not possible. Your solution would suggest changing the `MyClass`.

Comment: It's almost always possible to change the type declarations for a package, by last resort writing your own, but depending on the complexity of the package can be a lot of work.

Comment: Would you simply override the constructor of the class & write my own implementation of MyType or is there a smarter way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Could narrowing it down like that work for you ?

```
const myVar = new MyClass('exampleId', (params) => {
    if ("param1" in params && 'param2' in params) {
        return params.param1 * params.param2
    }
    return 0; // or whatever other default value 
});
```